# BitmapIndexScan vs IndexScan tuning

Tags: postgresql, index

I have the following test case:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS long;
SET search_path TO long,pg_temp,pg_catalog;
CREATE TABLE long WITH (autovacuum_enabled=off) AS
SELECT id, (random()*1000)::int AS key, random() AS value1, random() AS value2,
       repeat((random()*9)::int::text, 312) AS long
  FROM generate_series(1,10000000) id;
CREATE INDEX i_long_value1 ON long (value1);
CREATE INDEX i_long_wo ON long(key,value2 DESC);
VACUUM ANALYZE long;
```

Now, if I explain the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM long WHERE key=5 AND value1 BETWEEN 0.5 AND 0.6 ORDER BY value2 DESC;
```

I always get the [following plan](http://explain.depesz.com/s/cq6).
This is strange, for I have a matching index `i_long_wo`. So I use: `SET enable_bitmapscan TO off;` and this results in the [much better plan](http://explain.depesz.com/s/bHyV). This is reproducible on all PG instances I've tried (win64, HP-UX, MacOS) and not only on 9.4beta2. Also, I've run these queries several times prior to looking into the plans, to makes sure all information is cached, you can check `Buffers: shared hit` entries in the presented plans.

I am running on a (same effect observed on 9.1-9.4b2 on MacOS also):

```
postgres=# SELECT version();
                            version
----------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.4beta2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

postgres=# SELECT name,setting,unit,source FROM pg_settings
            WHERE NOT source IN ('default','override');
             name             |      setting       | unit |        source
------------------------------+--------------------+------+----------------------
 application_name             | psql               |      | client
 bgwriter_delay               | 50                 | ms   | configuration file
 bgwriter_lru_maxpages        | 350                |      | configuration file
 checkpoint_completion_target | 0.9                |      | configuration file
 checkpoint_segments          | 100                |      | configuration file
 client_encoding              | WIN1252            |      | client
 DateStyle                    | ISO, MDY           |      | configuration file
 default_text_search_config   | pg_catalog.english |      | configuration file
 dynamic_shared_memory_type   | windows            |      | configuration file
 effective_cache_size         | 524288             | 8kB  | configuration file
 lc_messages                  | C                  |      | configuration file
 lc_monetary                  | C                  |      | configuration file
 lc_numeric                   | C                  |      | configuration file
 lc_time                      | C                  |      | configuration file
 listen_addresses             | *                  |      | configuration file
 log_destination              | stderr             |      | configuration file
 log_line_prefix              | %t                 |      | configuration file
 log_timezone                 | Europe/Helsinki    |      | configuration file
 logging_collector            | on                 |      | configuration file
 max_connections              | 100                |      | configuration file
 max_stack_depth              | 2048               | kB   | environment variable
 port                         | 5432               |      | configuration file
 shared_buffers               | 131072             | 8kB  | configuration file
 TimeZone                     | Europe/Helsinki    |      | configuration file
 wal_buffers                  | 2048               | 8kB  | configuration file
 work_mem                     | 16384              | kB   | configuration file
(26 rows)
```

Windows instance is using 9.4beta2 installer from EDB, I will update compile details as soon as I am around. Configuration used to build MacOS instance:

```
CONFIGURE = '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql-9.4/9.4beta2' '--enable-dtrace' \
  '--with-bonjour' '--with-gssapi' '--with-ldap' '--with-libxml' \
  '--with-libxslt' '--with-openssl' '--with-uuid=e2fs' '--with-pam' \
  '--with-perl' '--with-python' '--with-tcl' \
'CC=/usr/bin/clang' \
'CFLAGS=-Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.9' \
'LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/e2fsprogs/lib \
  -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/lib \
  -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names' \
'CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/e2fsprogs/include \
  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include'
LIBS = -lpgcommon -lpgport -lxslt -lxml2 -lpam -lssl -lcrypto -lgssapi_krb5 \
  -lz -lreadline -lm
```

So I am wondering — why BitmapIndexScan got better estimates?

I hit [this post from Tom Lane](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/14821.1149104747@sss.pgh.pa.us) (quite old) and as I understand, recommended way is to tune `*_cost` parameters. But thing is — cost is affected by the number of pages more, this is seen by the number of buffers PostgreSQL touches during execution, they comparable for both plans and are higher then the number of records returned. Therefore adjusting `random_page_cost` lowers cost for *both plans* and IndexScan never wins.

I tried increasing `cpu_index_tuple_cost`, I had to bump it up to `0.02` to make planner stop using `BitmapAnd`. In this setup BitmapIndexScan varian looks much better, but still looses to the IndexScan.

Is it possible to make planner give a better estimate for IndexScan here?

Comment: It is not quite clear which query these plans belong to.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: @jjanes, it is very stable for me, with similar plans on different OSes and different major versions. I doubt these are caching effects, I've been running queries hundreds of time. And I believe that cassert is off.

Comment: If you set `random_page_cost` to 1 (same as `seq_page_cost`), then index scan comes out cheaper and wins, on my system. If everything's in cache (which it is, in your examples: there are no buffers read), it makes sense. With it set to 1.5, a bit more realistic, I get the single bitmap scan with a filter, which to be fair is pretty close (~11ms vs ~8ms for the index scan). I think it's doing a fair job there - the cost estimates are not quite perfect but are close.

Comment: @hbn, I have the same results in my findings. Still, in this example cost for the `IndexScan` is too high IMO, especially with default settings. Adjusting `random_page_cost=1.5` might not be a good thing to do for workloads that have to read from disks.

Comment: Totally agree - but I think that's the point. The planner can't know a priori if reads for a plan will be cached or not, only estimate based on shared_buffers, effective_cache_size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run your example with a cold cache for both queries, then the bitmap index scan really does win out.  So in this sense, the planner is getting it correct.

Since you are testing under a perfectly hot cache, the correct thing to do would be to lower the `random_page_cost` and the `seq_page_cost` both to zero, and if I do that it does select the index scan you prefer (and at that point, I can't even get it to use the BitMapAnd, no matter what I do to the `enable_*` parameters).

This is not to say that the planner is doing a good job here.  It is vastly underestimating the amount of work that needs to be done to insert a tuple into a bitmap.  It assumes it takes 0.1 of a `cpu_operator_cost` to do so, which seems facially absurd to me.

If you measure your buffer hit/miss rates for this particular query under realistic conditions, rather than under benchmarking conditions, what do they look like?  It would be nice to do tests under realistic conditions, but those are very hard to achieve so I can just do all-hot or all-cold and hope it interpolates correctly

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate a bit more on how planer decides how many pages it will read during either of the Scans? Documentation explains only heap-related costs in details. As to the real conditions — I do this on educational grounds, so there's no real system with similar workload around.

Comment: @vyegorov bitmap index scans touch the same index pages as regular index scans so (or would, if a regular index scan were to be run on the same conditions).  The code that does the estimate is in src/backend/optimizer/path/costsize.c, index_pages_fetched.  But the problem here is in the CPU cost estimates, not the page estimates